# What is the appropriate moderation action for questions with no answers which will never have answers?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

What's the most appropriate "vote to close" reason (or other moderation action) for 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645461/webclient-request-dont-work-anymore-in-a-new-project?

This question showed up in a list of "answers:0 closed:0 webclient" search results I was using to find old unanswered questions. THis question will never be answered because the OP has answered his own question inside a revision of the question:

> EDIT:
>
> fixed the problem, it was my misstake, i gave the method the paramters
>   in the wrong order :(

If the question itself would be helpful to future visitors, I'd simply copy the OP's "answer" to a real SO answer, as recommended [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60151/136315).

But this question has, IMHO, no use to any future viewers. So it seems like closing is a more appropriate action.

But none of the "vote to close" reasons seem to apply.

Any ideas what to do when running across questions like this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> But this question has, IMHO, no use to any future viewers.

In that case I would close it as **too localized**, which is made for that kind of situation:

> **This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors**; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: Of course, absent-minded me neglected to actually close it myself. Thanks Kev ;)